# Maximum protection without using password/login

Tags: privacy

I want to hide my WordPress site (or any website) from the world and only allow certain users to enter. What's the best way of doing this without setting up user accounts and passwords? Or perhaps more precise, what's the maximum protection I can get without using accounts?

Of course, I've chosen to block search engines under settings->privacy already. But I've thought about blocking people from linking directly to images and files, how can that be done? Is it by putting all the uploads (files/images) in a hidden folder somewhere outside of the WP structure? How do I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: You can restrict IP's to access, will that do?

Comment: Not really, I don't know the IP's in advance. I was thinking maybe I could use sessions or check http referrer to force people to enter via the start page or stuff like that. But I think I'll go for feeela's suggestion and authorize via the htaccess file instead just to minimize the amount of time programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How to restrict access to uploaded files?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13872/how-to-restrict-access-to-uploaded-files/)

There's an answer there to help you restrict access to images and other downloadable files.

Answer (score 2):

To protect a whole site against access from anywhere (but allowing access for multiple users) you **need** some kind of password protection. The preferred/most-common method is to use [authorization via a .htaccess-file](http://www.addedbytes.com/lab/password-protect-a-directory-with-htaccess/). If you don't want to sharing out passwords, one other option is to [use certificates for logging in](http://www.impetus.us/~rjmooney/projects/misc/clientcertauth.html).

Comment: Maybe I should have marked your anwser instead, don't know :) Thanks for your effort!

Comment: But wait a minute, how do I authorize using .htaccess on a WP multisite website? It seems like the htaccess file must be in the directory it's supposed to protect, and I don't think I can have a folder with the same name as the site, for example www.example.com/mywebsite. What to do?

Comment: Ok, don't think I can. I'll use a wp account instead...