# Password protect some uploaded files, so only logged-in users can view them

Tags: uploads, attachments, media, media-library, security

I would like to protect some uploaded files, so that they are not publicly accessible (they are not accessible without a login).  I'm uploading some PDF files, and I'd like to mark some of them as protected, so they can't be accessed without a login on the Wordpress web site.

I'm currently using the Member Access, which lets me mark some posts and pages as protected (so only logged-in users can view them).  This is great.  However, it does not provide any way to protect media uploads (i.e., attachments).

Note that I do not want to protect all uploads, only some of them.  Some uploads need to be accessible to the public, while others should only be accessible to logged-in users.  I'd prefer to do this through the Wordpress administration interface (not a hairy .htaccess file that has to be manually administered).  I want something that is actually secure, not just security-through-obscurity.

How do I do this?

(I've read [How to Protect Uploads, if User is not Logged In?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/37144/16448), but it concerns methods to protect all uploads, not just some of them.  I've read [How to restrict access to uploaded files?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/13872/16448), but it focuses on security-through-obscurity.  This is close to [simple solution for restricting access to (some) uploads/downloads](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/100939/16448), but I'd prefer a solution that can be administered through the web interface if possible.)

Comment: I'm using this Prevent Direct Access plugin and find it quite useful. You can protect certain file uploads against the public and search engines right under your WordPress admin. https://wordpress.org/plugins/prevent-direct-access/ This version only allows you to protect maximum 3 files though.

Answer (score 2):

See my question and answer again, you linked it already in your question:

[simple solution for restricting access to (some) uploads/downloads](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/100939/simple-solution-for-restricting-access-to-some-uploads-downloads/101224#101224)

The solution isn't that hairy the only necessity - besides configuring the plugin correct - is to create a `.htaccess`, which you could do programmatically. For that you have to automate the creation of the `.htaccess` file inside the configured folder of wp-downloadmanager. On the other hand, you obviously read that...

You might want to take a look at this solution:
https://github.com/mattheu/Private-Media

Answer (score 1):

I use the combination of these two plugins:

Create the Download page and facilitate uploading of new content:
http://wordpress.org/plugins/download-monitor/

Protect wordpress site to allow trusted users to access the site: 
http://andrey.eto-ya.com/wordpress/my-plugins/trusted-only

Though I used it to protect the whole site not just specific downloads.

Comment: Right, I don't want to protect the whole site.  I just want to limit access to certain downloads, not all of them, and not the whole site.  Thank you, though!